# ssis renaming a file wthout knowing existing name

Tags: csv, ssis, filesystems, renaming

I have set up part of my ssis package to check a folder and move the csv file to another folder using a file system task.

Is it possible to rename a file without knowing what the source name will be? as I have been told it will be a new name on a daily bases. can I use a wildcard in a file system task? would I be best renaming before moving what is best practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an unknown file name you can wrap your file system task in a foreach loop

1. wrap your file system task in a foreach loop and set to file enumerate
2. set the folder to your source location
3. set search string to *.csv
4. set to full file path
5. map to a variable called fname
6. use fname as variable in file system task for source

Make sure you delay validation on connection manager

Comment: Also note that you do not need to move the file to process it. You can use that variable as the location of the file to be processed and process from the location without knowing the actual file name.